# Paginate all images from a directory on a WordPress web page

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

I need to show in a `PHP` web page all the images in a folder. A pagination is required. The images can be more than 10,000, so a good performance is important, and here is where my doubt comes from, what is more efficient?

- Paginate the images of the folder using `scandir`.
- Automatically save the name of all images in a database and load them with a `Mysqli` query (probably also convenient to use a temporary cache).
- Any other suggestions you can give me.

The website uses `WordPress` as the engine, but the images are uploaded to a subdomain using a PHP file isolated from Wordpress ...

I thought about saving the name of all the images like a `WordPress Custom-Post-Type` (using `mysqli` basic queries) and paginate them like any other publication, but I think that, due to the amount, it would harm the overall performance of the website (because the `custom-post-type` are saved in the same table as the other publications)...

The website receives more than 30 thousand daily visits that it must support.

*PD: Sorry for the bad explanation but it is complicated to explain, and more in another language.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom table or a second database.

You are right to consider avoiding repeatedly calling scandir for every paginated request. 
You can access the global `$wpdb` object and do custom queries to manage the contents of your directory.

I'd lean towards just managing the image data separately from WordPress. Since you are already using a non WP upload script just create a new DB and use it to keep track of the directory contents in that script. Then paginated results is a very simple DB query. This keeps the WP database smaller and faster and is not overkill for the magnitude of images and visits you must handle.